# How to store a full column from a csv as a dictionary value?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to store one or multiple columns of a csv (without delimiter, header and index) as a value in a dictionary.

Example:

```
csv: 
numbers
17
28
93 
14
5

dictionary:
"foo":  {
             17
             28
             93 
             14
             5
         }
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes.  What have *you* tried and researched on your own before asking for help?

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for this but it might be abit of an overkill.

```py
import pandas as pd
dictionary = pd.read_csv('/tmp/t.csv').to_dict()
dictionary

{'numbers': {0: 17, 1: 28, 2: 93, 3: 14, 4: 5}}
```